# Delete certificate for specific website

Tags: mac, google-chrome, certificate

When I go to github, Chrome warns me that "The site's security certificate is not trusted!"

I am sure I am using the correct URL. When I go to the same URL in Firefox, I don't get this issue.

How do I delete/refresh what my Mac believes to be Github's certificate in Chrome?

Comment: I don't have this issue with Chrome and github. Some of the suggestions below are off base. Copy and past the URL from the Chrome address bar here so we can see (actually from the address bar in Chrome or it's a waste of time). Also if you know how please provide the IP address your computer things it maps to (ie ping (or dig or nslookup) github.com and show the IP displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the lock icon in the address bar to get more information about the certificate. That said, to allow a untrused certificate without the warning you must add it to the certificate store. You will find the certificate settings under Settings -> Show advanced settings... -> HTTPS/SSL -> Manage certificates...

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** -> **Show advanced settings** -> **Manage certificates**.
Ps: This message also appears when the computer's time is wrong.

Comment: So this is what I originally did...and it just opens up Keychain Access and I'm more or less lost on what to do next. I clicked through everything but didn't see anything that said github.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. You just have to delete cookies for that particular site **Privay -> Content Settings -> All cookies and site data**